# Visual Studio corrupted my Windows 7 after power failure, in the middle of installation

Tags: bsod, power, visual-studio-2012

I was at the middle of Visual Studio 2012 installation that the power went off!

after I turned my computer on, Windows 7 boots up with welcome screen and an empty dialog like the picture below:
[image: empty dialog]

then i faced this dialog:
[image: error]

and after a while a blue screen:
[image: blue screen]

I have tested the following cases to repair the issue:

1. I am not able to open task manager, in order to open the `explorer.exe`
2. there is no Visual Studio item to uninstall on safe mode.
3. the installation can not run on safe mode, in order to uninstall or repair.
4. there is no restore point to restore my windows.

So, how can i fix it?

Comment: in safe mode can you launch msconfig from run > place windows in Diagnostics startup and reboot to see if you can login normally?

Comment: This isn't caused by Visual Studio based on the BSOD.

Comment: @CharlesH, fixed! it logged in, i started the windows installer service and reinstalled the visual studio. post it as answer to receive your reputation award.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In safe mode can you launch msconfig from run > place windows in Diagnostics startup and reboot to see if you can login normally?

Glad you got it fixed Martin!